# how to sort a particular value at the end?

Tags: mysql, sql, case, sql-order-by

how can i display the word Not Listed at the very bottom so that even in my dropdown menu it shows at the botton?

```
items
-------

id    name

1     some name 1
2     some name 2
3     some name 3
4     Not Listed
5     some name 4
6     some name 5
```

what will the query be like for this?

Currently my query is like

```
SELECT *
FROM items
ORDER BY id DESC
```

Thanks

Comment: currently my query is like SELECT * FROM items ORDER BY if DESC

Comment: You should store null, not a string value, for unlisted items.

Comment: Poor sample data, you should have names alphabetically both before and after 'Not Listed'. And also specify the expected result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM items
ORDER BY name
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a first level of sorting that puts names with value `Not Listed` last:

```
select *
from items
order by (name = 'Not Listed'), id desc
```

Expression `(name = 'Not Listed')` returns `1` when the conition is met, otherwise `0`. So this does give priority to records where name is other than `'Not Listed'`.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3da12b865521cedb81070b48a7438ae8)**:

```
id | name       
-: | :----------
 6 | some name 5
 5 | some name 4
 3 | some name 3
 2 | some name 2
 1 | some name 1
 4 | Not Listed
```

Comment: Will this take the Not Listed at the very bottom?

Comment: what will happen to my ORDER BY id DESC?

Comment: @Rick: yes. I added an explanation and a demo to my answer for your reference.